# Discord JS v13 Embed Welcome Message Error

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

This is my Code rn but there is coming an error

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Willkommen')
        .addField(member.nickname)
        .setImage(member.user.avatarURL)

    member.guild.channels.get('896102767486189648').send(exampleEmbed);
})
```

this is the Error:

```
 if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);
                                  ^

RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_NAME]: MessageEmbed field names must be non-empty strings.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your [`.addField`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addField) function is wrong, It should be like this

```js
.addField('Field title','Field value', true) // The last one tells if the field's option 'inline' is set to true or not
```

In your case it should be

```js
.addField('Nickname', member.nickname)
```

Here's an [`example`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor) about embeds if you want to learn more.